# Is it possible to use cloneNode to clone multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, clone

I'm trying to clone to divs in and append them to to other divs (their parents). I'm using clonenode for this but it doesn't seem to work. It clones the div in the first function and appends it to the parent of the div in the second function! Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Here's the code (**EDIT:**var added):

```
function cloneQ() {
    //Cloning questions and shit
    cloneQ.id = (cloneQ.id || 0) + 1;
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    var clone = question.cloneNode(true);
    var numberOfQuestions = $('.question').length;
    var id = "questioncon" + cloneQ.id;
    clone.id = id;
    question.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    var inid = "question" + cloneQ.id;
    var optionid = "optionsdiv" + cloneQ.id;
    $('#' + id + ' ' + '.' + 'questionin').attr('id', inid);
    $('#' + id + ' ' + '.' + 'options').attr('id', optionid);
    $('#' + id + ' h2').html('Question ' + cloneQ.id);

    //Question Cloned
    }

function cloneforPrint() {
    cloneforPrint.id = (cloneforPrint.id || 0) + 1;
    var questionprint = document.getElementById("questionprint");
    var cloneprint = questionprint.cloneNode(true);
    var printid = "questionprint" + cloneforPrint.id;
    cloneprint.id = printid;
    questionprint.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    var printinid = "thequestionprint" + cloneforPrint.id;
    $('#' + printid + ' ' + '.' + 'thequestionprint').attr('id', printinid);
}
```

LIVE here: http://bit.ly/R8hB2m

Comment: Please.. don't mix DOM with jQuery. **And indent your code properly!**

Comment: Why not though? The few lines of jQuery I used would be way harder with just Javscript, no?

Comment: Forcing people to context switch when trying to understand your code is bad. Do it all in jQuery or do it all without jQuery.

Comment: @PeterWilkinson - I don't agree that you use all jQuery or all plain javascript.  Each are tools and `this.id` makes a lot more sense in a jQuery event handler than `$(this).attr("id")`.  One should use the most appropriate tools for the job while writing readable and maintainable code.  It is OK to mix and match in many cirucmstances.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Fair point. Readable code is the goal. In most situations this means mixing is bad, but there are exceptions. I've certainly never bothered to use the attr('id') syntax.

Comment: Yes, `this.id` etc. are fine. But when you start calling DOM 
*methods* it quickly becomes an ugly mix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : Global vars are the problem.

You aren't putting var in front of your variables, making them global. The cloneForPrint function is picking up vars defined in cloneQ.

Init all the variables properly and you'll get some errors indicating where the problems are.

CloneQ is indeed appending to questions parent, but cloneForPrint then moves it somewhere else.

-- Old answer --

There's not enough here to work out what the problem is. My 1st guess is that the `question` element has the same parent as the `questionprint` element.

Based on the code given, `cloneQ` should definitely append to `question`s parent. So to give the appearance you've specified the DOM probably doesn't look like what you expect.

Comment: it's live here: http://bit.ly/R8hB2m, could you check it out, please?and I'm 100% sure the parents are not the same.

Comment: that worked, except the second function cloneforprint isn't working now!

Comment: Yes, now that the global vars are gone the 2nd function is throwing a JavaScript error. Fix the error.

Comment: fixed it. Turned out I was appending the clone variable from the first function instead of cloneprint variable from the second function. Thanks!